# Java reference variable - Symbol not found

Tags: java, variables, reference

This program is demonstration of object reference variables of class

```
class Super1
{
  final int num1=22;
  final int num2=10;
}

class add extends Super1
{
  add()
  {
    System.out.println("object of class add created");
  }
  void result()
  {
    System.out.println("The additon of two numbers: "+(num1+num2));
  }
  protected void finalize()
  {
    System.out.println("Object of class add Destroyed");
  }
}

class sub extends Super1
{
  sub()
  {
    System.out.println("class sub object created");
  }
  void result()
  {
    System.out.println("The sustraction of two numbers is"+(num1-num2));
  }
  protected void finalize()
  {
    System.out.println("Sub class object destroyed");
  }
}

class i111
{
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    Super1 ref;
    add obj1=new add();
    sub obj2=new sub();

    ref=obj1;
    ref.result();
    obj1=null;

    ref=obj2;
    ref.result();
    obj2=null;
  }
}
```

After Compiling I'm getting

> error: cannot find Symbol   ref.result(); symbol: method result()
>   location: variable ref of type Super1

Comment: (1) Please ident your code, it's unreadable. (2) Are your methods package protected by intention?

Comment: The error says,  `Super1` class has not any `result()` method.

Comment: No,methods are not part of any package.All the code is in one single file

Comment: @Viber: In order to call `result ()`, you must first cast `ref`to `((add) ref).result ()`. Only this way, `result()`will be visible :-) And please learn [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html). Class names should be in `Pascal`case.

Answer (score 1):

You declare a variable ref, of type `Super1`:

```
Super1 ref;
```

And you try to call method `result()` on this variable:

```
ref.result();
```

But Super1 is defined as

```
class Super1 {
    final int num1=22;
    final int num2=10;
}
```

So it doesn't have any `result()` method, hence the error.